# Regular Expression to get all matched position

Tags: c#, regex

Let's take this code snippet

```
var input = @"
a:1
b:22

a:3
b:44
";

var pattern = @"b:([^\n]+)\n";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

And the result I get in match is at the below snapshot.

How can we get the list of values of `b` e.g. {22, 44}?

I can only see the 22.

[image]

Comment: There should be a NextMatch method

Comment: Personally, I would rather do two splits (one at `Environment.Newline`, one at `:`) than using Regex here.

Comment: You could use `Matches` instead of `Match`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Regex.Matches` method instead of `Regex.Match`. Here's an example from MSDN

```
string pattern = "a*";
string input = "abaabb";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) 
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
```

if you want a list of matched values

```
Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Match`, use `Matches` method to get multiple matches in one go:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++ )
{
    var value = matches[i].Value;
}
```

or using `foreach` syntax:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var value = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit No, he means `foreach (Match match in matches)`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The end result is the same though, you can achieve the same goal using different ways.

Answer (score 2):

> Returns a new Match object with the results for the next match, starting at the position at which the last match ended (at the character after the last matched character).

[Match.NextMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

What could be even easier, is to just loop through all `Matches`.